# opengl fixed function uses gpu or cpu?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-10.04

I have a code which basically draws parallel coordinates using opengl fixed func pipeline. 
The coordinate has 7 axes and draws 64k lines. SO the output is cluttered, but when I run the code on my laptop which has intel i5 proc, 8gb ddr3 ram it runs fine. One of my friend ran the same code in two different systems both having intel i7 and 8gb ddr3 ram along with a nvidia gpu. In those systems the code runs with shuttering and sometimes the mouse pointer becomes unresponsive. If you guys can give some idea why this is happening, it would be of great help. Initially I thought it would run even faster in those systems as they have a dedicated gpu. My own laptop has ubuntu 12.04 and both the other systems have ubuntu 10.x.

Comment: Presumably you have the correct drivers installed for the hardware in each system.  Check the OpenGL vendor string, `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` to see who's really doing the rendering.

Comment: hi radical7,
I got following info:

Vendor Info:   NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer Info:   GeForce GT 650M/PCIe/SSE2
GL Version Info:   4.3.0 NVIDIA 310.19

Answer (score 0):

Fixed function pipeline is implemented using gpu programmable features in modern opengl drivers. This means most of the work is done by the GPU. Fixed function opengl shouldn't be any slower than using glsl for doing the same things, but just really inflexible.

What do you mean by coordinates having axes and 7 axes? Do you have screen shots of your application?

Mouse stuttering sounds like you are seriously taxing your display driver. This sounds like you are making too many opengl calls. Are you using immediate mode (glBegin glVertex ...)? Some OpenGL drivers might not have the best implementation of immediate mode. You should use vertex buffer objects for your data.

Comment: thanks for the reply, 7 axes means in my parallel coordinate plot I am plotting 7 features. All the drawing are basically using glBegin and glEnd. But It is working fine in my laptop which does not have any external gpu and causing problems on the other two systems equipped with nvidia gpu, which is weird. I believe that what I am doing, both those machines are easily capable of doing that without any issue... opengl gave following results

Vendor Info:   NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer Info:   GeForce GT 650M/PCIe/SSE2
GL Version Info:   4.3.0 NVIDIA 310.19

Comment: Just use vertex arrays or vertex buffer objects then. NVIDIA's immediate mode is probably not optimized at all, because nobody should be using it anyways. Also on intel graphics there is probably less latency between cpu and igp than using pci-express, so it's not as big of a deal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood you, but here I go.

There are API calls such as glBegin, glEnd which give commands to the GPU, so they are using GPU horsepower, though there are also calls to arrays, other function which have no relation to API - they use CPU.
Now it's a good practice to preload your models outside the onDraw loop of the OpenGL by saving the data in buffers (glGenBuffers etc) and then use these buffers(VBO/IBO) in your onDraw loop.

If managed correctly it can decrease the load on your GPU/CPU. Hope this helps.

Oleg

Comment: hi Oleg, thanks for the reply..ya I get your point and I have used VBO previously and now thinking about rewriting it using VBO, but I just don't understand why a more powerful computer having difficulty while a less powerful cpu only system rendering the whole thing without any hiccup! seems wired to me..

Comment: Unfortunately I come from android and iOS development with OpenGL. So I'm unfamiliar with the ubuntu systems. But I think the OpenGL pipeline is the same for all the systems working with OpenGL. Try to check your code for memory leaks I know that on android there is DDMS, which can help you with that, on iOS it's Xcode. The java SDK got jmap for that. Also as I mentioned before if you have cluttering during the rendering phase that means that your rendering functions makes too much calculations.